# Is there a way to 2-way bind $index from ng-repeat on a model without javascript, using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to have a list of dom elements like that:

```
<div ng-repeat="element in elements track by $index" 
     data-index="$index" ng-init="element.order = $index"> </div>
```

---

```
If the elements are 3 then
elements[0].order = 0;
elements[1].order = 1;
elements[2].order = 2;
```

I am trying to bind $index on each of the elements on the field 'order'. Obviously data-index is not 2-way binding and ng-init effect disappears after the element is replaced with a new object in my code. I would like to be able to change automatically the 'order' fields of elements based on the DOM order (e.g if I have a drag-n-drop reorder mechanism). How can this be done without Javascript by just using angular bindings in HTML?

Comment: angular is javascript.

Comment: It is obvious .. it is not just javascript.. I mean no ctrl/directive javascript code..

Comment: I don't get the need. But, does this make sense :- <div order={{ $index }}>

Comment: this doesn't bind it to the model automatically..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I raised this issue in git (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12312) and the angular team responded that there is core support for that:

`ng-attr-xxx` can be used to bind html order field with model order field

So this:

```
<div ng-repeat="element in elements track by $index" ng-attr-xxx="element.order = $index"> </div>
```

is doing what I want.

:)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this is what you want?

```
<div ng-repeat="element in elements track by $index | orderBy:'order'" ng-model="element.order" ng-init="element.order = $index"></div>
```

Using `ng-init` is considered bad though so I would not recommend doing this. You should be initializing it in a controller instead.

Comment: let me try that - edit: ng-model will be invalid with expression

Comment: I don't think `ng-model` can be an expression

Comment: @Chrillewoodz ng-model never initialized order .. only ng-init does it but it gets lost if I replace the object with a new one

Comment: It seems like you're asking the impossible here, is there a reason for not wanting to use js?

Comment: my real life example is way more complicated than this with multi-level hierarchies and multiple orders per element and tie-breakers and I would like to not go through that pain. If there was something like ng-order="element.order" it would take care of it automatically

Comment: Create your own directive that do just that then?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to bind it? You can always get the index of an element in an array using `indexOf`

```
var elements = [100,200,300,400];
var index = elements.indexOf(200); // 1
```

If you need the value in HTML, you can use it there as well

```
<div ng-show="elements.indexOf(element) == 3">
```

Comment: well if I have to introduce any javascript for that then I know many ways that I can do it. Thanks though

Comment: I was not suggesting using JS. I was asking why would you store something that you already have / can always retrieve?

Comment: well if I use some javascript and move things around or remove elements I will have to make the indices consistent and contiguous .. I don't know if I use splice how the index of the array would work